# Is it possible to select a range of cells and include charts?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I have an excel sheet that shows a report. I want to take that report, and format it nicely into an email.

I used some very helpful code I found [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) to get started. It works [almost] great! The only problem is my report in the sheet contains charts, that I would like copied over into the email as well.

Is there a way to get my charts over into the HTML as well? Or into the email body in their rightful positions? I don't think selecting the range and ALSO selecting all charts on sheet would work, and don't think it's even possible to select both at once to process them into the HTML.

Another method I tried was copying the range as a picture, this works but the picture is very small. Is there a way to make it larger? Here is the code for that:

```
Function emailaspic()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Report").Range("A1:V182")
rng.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Object
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Object
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture


End Function
```

Thank you all in advance! I've tried googling this exact scenario and thought it would be common, but haven't found someone who is trying to get the range AND the charts at the same time...